# looked old to sb

Tags: meaning-in-context

[source](http://khnovel.com/halo-the-fall-of-reach/page-5-121249.html)

> A woman stood on the top step and beckoned to them. She wore a white
>   sheet wrapped around her body.
>
> She looked **old** to John, yet **young** at the same time.

I guess "she looked old to John" means "John was young, so she was old in John's eyes". "yet young at the same time" means "actually, she was young", right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"She looked old to John" just means *She appeared old to John*, without any information about John's age range. John could be young or old. It is not *because* John was young, the woman looked old in comparison.

> She looked old to John, yet young at the same time.

This sentence suggests that the woman appears both old and young at the same time to John. A little further down the story tells you:

> Then he saw the motes of light orbiting her head and knew she was an AI.

I gather that your source is a Sci Fi story and the woman is an AI/robot. So it is no surprise John can't get a bead on the woman's exact age.